# How to dump Filename,File size to txt via batch

Tags: batch

I am scratching my head... I have not used batch code in ages and was wondering if anyone here could help me.

Basically, I have a basic batch I use to dump the contents of a folder to a txt file

```
dir /a /b /-p /o:gen >C:\file_list.txt
start notepad C:\file_list.txt
```

Simple stuff, I just can't remember for the life of me how to add the filesize of each file as well to the outputted txt file

Any help would be great... It's something simple... Just can't remember...

Answer (score 1):

#### How can I add the filesize of each file as well to the output txt file?

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a /b /-p /o:gen') do (
  echo %%i %%~zi >> C:\file_list.txt
  )
start notepad C:\file_list.txt
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [syntax-args](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - Command Line arguments (Parameters)

Comment: That would corrupt file names containing spaces as default delimiter is a space.

Comment: @ZX81v2 Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button).