# Show tree view and size of individual files/folders in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I would like to be able to view the file structure and individual file/folder sizes of an external hard drive. I am looking for a solution similar to using `tree /f > tree.txt` in the  command prompt but which also includes the file size. I have looked at answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518646/tree-view-of-a-directory-folder-in-windows) which is where I found the above solution. I will need to instruct someone with general computing skills to do this so a solution with similar simplicity would be ideal. I think they will likely be using Windows 8.

I have also had a look at this [solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1326244/how-to-dump-filename-file-size-to-txt-via-batch) but can't get it to work. Do I need to edit the below batch file with a file path? Where does this go?

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /a /b /-p /o:gen') do (
  echo %%i %%~zi >> C:\file_list.txt
  )
start notepad C:\file_list.txt
```

Thank you!